# APP_INITIALIZER in angular 2.4.x has stopped working

Tags: angular

I have APP_INITIALIZER preloading my config which was working fine till i have upgraded from 2.0.2 to 2.4.2

I am the only one experiencing this problem?

```
providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (config:ConfigService) => () => {
            return config.load();
        },
    deps: [ConfigService, Http],
    multi: true
},
.........
```

config.loda() is getting intiilasied after componetns and servics

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed since https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/14681. Please try angular 2.4.9. Thanks. :)